# Remove leading blank space from CSV results in insertion of blank rows and deletion of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, null, whitespace

With the following (note the first row has no leading space):

```
Test1@bigfoot.com
 Test11@bigfoot.com
 Test1111@bigfoot.com
 Test111ew@bigfoot.com
 Test12312@bigfoot.com
 Test1231321@bigfoot.com
 Test1342321@bigfoot.com
 ....
 481 total rows
```

The following correctly removes the leading space, but inserts a blank row after each string row, AND, **truncates** the total list by a random number of rows each time it is executed.

```
csvfile= open('list.csv','r')
csvfile1= open('complete_list.csv','w')
stripped = (row.strip() for row in csvfile)
reader = csv.reader(stripped,delimiter=' ')
writer= csv.writer(csvfile1)
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow([e.strip() for e in row])
```

And:

```
with open('list.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
    for row in reader:
        row.update({fieldname: value.strip() for (fieldname, value) in row.items()})
```

Does nothing, as the first row is assumed to be the fieldname, when in fact it is simply...a row.

Comment: try `open('complete_list.csv','w',newline="")`

Comment: That solved the blank line issue, but is still truncating the list: Output only has 459 rows,should have the 481 from the original CSV, which is why the question is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: you should probably do `csvfile1.close()` before reading it back again (flush buffers)

Comment: Regardless of where I put csvfile1.close(), it returns I/O operation on closed file

Comment: it's not the close operation that returns this, it's a read/write performed _after_ having closed the file.

Comment: I'm confused. If the only call to csvfile1 is to open it in write mode, how does closing it before writing to it accomplish that?

Comment: check my answer, I'm proposing a solution without "close". The small fixes I'm proposing should make your code work (of course I didn't test with your data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several issues here:

- csv files must be opened in write mode with `newline=""` in python 3, else it insert blanks on windows
- don't use `strip` but `lstrip` on the lines, else it removes newline at the end of the line. Can confuse csv reader
- use `with` context block so it ensures that the files are closed when exiting the block (should handle your random missing lines in the end)

my proposal:

```
with open('list.csv','r') as csvfile, open('complete_list.csv','w',newline="") as csvfile1:  # newline="" to avoid blanks
    stripped = (row.lstrip() for row in csvfile)  # lstrip not strip
    reader = csv.reader(stripped,delimiter=' ')
    writer= csv.writer(csvfile1)
    writer.writerows(reader)   # don't overstrip: just write rows as-is
```

Comment: Ahh that did it! I was drawing a complete blank on the correct order of closing/opening preparatory to writing thanks!